# viewstate in database? is it convenient?

Tags: c#, asp.net, database, viewstate

I've an asp.net page which there is a multiview control inside. Within the control there are many many textboxes, selects and dynamically created tables. Therefore, I believe I have to use the viewstate on each postback. However, I'm afraid that the page size will increase and will slow down the reload time. So, I'm thinking to move the viewstate in a database. Is it convenient? Or are there any other ways to overcome this problem.

Thanks in advance

Comment: http://www.eggheadcafe.com/articles/20040613.asp

Comment: How do you think storing it in the database would improve your load time? You'd still have to transmit the information, and now you've added overhead from accessing the database.

Comment: To speed it up, do this EnableViewState="false"  :)

Comment: Nice link @Muhammad. If you check the link @Anna you can see that there are more convinient ways to use regular viewstate :) Btw, @Jack, since I have to store the textbox values and other stuff, I cannot think another way to store them and retrieve in postback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a page such as the one you're describing you need to ask yourself a few things.

First, do you need to save the state of all the controls? Probably not. For controls you won't need to remember the state of, turn the viewstate off for them.

Second, do you really need so many post backs? Could you instead write an ajax call that won't blow away the page with a postback? Doing this will help improve your user experience as well as reduce the number of elements needed in your viewstate.

Third, for dynamically created controls, you will need to manage the objects yourself anyway so you might as well turn viewstate off for them.

To answer your actual question, no storing your view state in a DB is not a good idea. That will slow down your page and will over complicate things to the extreme. If two people are on your page, how are you going to make sure there isn't cross contamination? How many people will be hitting this page? What would you index that table one to keep it from being stupid slow? See...complex already.

I would sit down and think about the design of this page before going forward. If it's a bloated catch all page, perhaps you need to get creative with how you implement it to give your users a good experience.

Comment: you're right, I will indeed use Ajax and javascript. But that's the second step, first of all I want to create a page that works fully without javascript. Then I will implement the client side script. Reason 1: I want to learn some stuff in c# and asp.net since I'm new at this. Reason 2: I want it to work in my mobile phone which is a Blackberry that does not include javascript :) Thanks for the anwser.

Answer (score 0):

First of all viewstate is old technique, but if you must use "Classic" ASP.NET methodologies then yeah you answer is try turn off viewstate on controls that do not need persisting state, such would be label controls where you are just should text and secondly move it to a state server if you have such option.

If you are keep on optimising such have a look at MVC3 http://www.asp.net/mvc + JQuery + Ajax. Large projects are done with such technologies, one for example is this very site. :) :)